# Google Calendar API: update event with OAuth 2.0 , getting response 403 forbidden

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

using scopes:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

With the method

> PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId

place of calendarId passing : xxxx.com_12312312312xxxx@resource.calendar.google.com

place of eventId passing: 1lkxxxxxxadtxxxxsdss

In body I have passed the event object.
In event Object I have updated the attendee list , removed resource room from attendee

passing the Bearer Token

but in response getting : 403 forbidden error

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "message": "Forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you provide the code related to the request you are making?